# Insert trigger checking for specific column

Tags: sql-server

I have got an insert trigger on a table. The table got a field named 'source'.
The source field could be populated with values b or left empty as in null.
i want the trigger only to fire if the source field is not populated with 'b'.
The below trigger codes deosnt give me error, but never runs.
if i remove the if condition it runs, but i need to check for value of 'b' before it should run.

```
Create TRIGGER TriggerName
ON tableName
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @source nvarchar(50)

SELECT                  @source = (select source  from inserted)

             if not (@source = 'b') 
                begin

                INSERT INTO ATable
                (field1,field2,field3)  
                SELECT i.field1,i.field2,i.field3
                FROM inserted i 

                    end
end
```

Comment: For one, your trigger doesn't handle the case `INSERT dbo.TableName(source) VALUES('b'),(NULL);`. A trigger fires once per DML action, not once per row. So assigning something from `inserted` to a variable is bad news.

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749220/sql-server-insert-trigger-checking-for-specific-column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Aaron Bertrand you should do this ..

```
Create TRIGGER trigger_testtable
ON dbo.test
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

            INSERT INTO ATable
            (field1,field2,field3)  
            SELECT i.field1,i.field2,i.field3
            FROM inserted i 
                where (i.[source] IS NULL OR i.[source] <> 'b')

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to re-create what you're doing on my local instance, here's what I've got:-

I created two tables, one for the data to be inserted to and one for the trigger to insert to:-

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[TriggerTest]
(Source         CHAR(1),
 TestColSource  CHAR(1));
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[InsertTest]
(TestColDest CHAR(1));
GO
```

I then created this trigger (as @Aaron Bertrand says, removing the variable assignment):-

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TriggerTest
ON dbo.[TriggerTest]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[InsertTest]
        (TestColDest)  
    SELECT i.TestColSource
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.SOURCE <> 'b'
END
```

I then inserted some data into the initial table:-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[TriggerTest]
SELECT 'a', '1'
UNION
SELECT 'b', '2'
UNION 
SELECT 'c', '3'
```

The trigger should only insert the 1 & 3 values from the above statement, but this can be checked by:-

```
SELECT TestColDest FROM dbo.[InsertTest]
```

Hopefully that should give you a basis for your trigger. I'm sure the guys on here will correct me if I've got something wrong.

Comment: @DBAFromTheCold .. Needs to check for `NULL` as `WHERE i.SOURCE <> 'b'` will not work if NULL is in `Source`

Comment: Thanks, adding AND i.source IS NOT NULL should do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i do not have enough points to vote up but you and t_m pointed in the right direction.